# How to override exit action (iphone dev.)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I need to write some information to file before exiting application. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your app supports multitasking (and you're on iOS 4 or above):

Override the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method in your app delegate, and do like the follwing:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {



bgTask = [ [UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

//do whatever writing you like    


if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following method in your App Delegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with [Preserving the State of Your Application’s User Interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23) on Apple's Developer site. Read about the methods `applicationDidEnterBackground:` and it's related methods like `applicationWillResignActive`, etc. One thing to keep in mind when implementing any of these application delegate methods is that you don't have a lot of time to do stuff.

One way to avoid the race condition of trying to write out some data while the app is being backgrounded or exiting is to write it out when it changes during the normal course of your app running. Then, it's always correct "on disk."